# Improving the proof by contraposition / why it works

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, intuition

This is the problem

```
 Prove that if n is an integer and 3n+2 is odd, then n is odd
```

So for this I should take $3n+2$ to be true and assume $\lnot q$, therefore I can say $n = 2k$. Then $$3n+2=$$$$3(2k)+2=$$ $$6k+2 =$$ $$2(3k+1)$$

Now because at the outset I said $3n+2$ is odd and then showed that if $n$ is even then $3n+2 = 2(3k+1)$ which is even. Why does this prove $p \to q$ ?

Also, my professor is a bit strict and if we don't write it all out "formally" he takes a significant amount of points off even though the proof might be correct. Could someone rewrite this in a "formal" way?

Comment: @crash yes, at least for this one

Comment: *Why* is $p\to q\equiv \neg q\to\neg p$? Have you considered writing up a truth table?

Comment: I can see why $p \to q$ is logically equivalent to $\lnot q \to \lnot p$ from a truth table but this still doesn't let me understand why. I'm wondering if I can get an explanation in words

Comment: How about this: "If the weather is cold, then I'm cold. If I'm not cold, then the weather is not cold."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple contraposition proof without any fluff:

Suppose $n$ is even. Then $n=2\ell$, where $\ell\in\mathbb{Z}$. Thus,
$$
3n+2=3(2\ell)+2=2(3\ell+1)=2m,\quad m\in\mathbb{Z}
$$
Thus, if $n$ is even, then $3n+2$ is even; that is, if $3n+2$ is odd, then $n$ is odd.